# Android Studio: How do I get wrap_content + value?

Tags: java, android, xml

I want to get a value slightly larger than what WRAP_CONTENT is giving me in Android Studio. In other words, I want to programatically get a dynamic value that is calculated from WRAP_CONTENT.

Here is what I currently have:

```
val messageText = TextView(applicationContext)
var lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

messageText.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lp)
```

What I want is something like this:

```
val messageText = TextView(applicationContext)
var lp = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT + 20, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT + 20)

messageText.layoutParams = ViewGroup.LayoutParams(lp)
```

However the text just fails to show up. I just need a size slightly larger than what my WRAP_CONTENT is giving me. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: wouldn't padding do the job?

Comment: @Dmitri Well, the problem is that I want to pad my textView, but because it is only rendering the size of the text itself, padding does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Make use of margin spacing within your Textview to get the desired results!